# Need help understanding an algorithm that employs Arrays.sort()

Tags: java, string, comparator, compareto

**Problem**

Given a list of non negative integers, arrange them such that they form the largest number.

E.g.  Input: [3,30,34,5,9] Output: "9534330"

**Solution**

```
public class Solution {
    // DO NOT MODIFY THE LIST
    public String largestNumber(final List<Integer> a) {

    String[] arr = new String[a.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        arr[i] = String.valueOf(a.get(i));
    }


    Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<String>(){
        public int compare(String a, String b){
            return (b+a).compareTo(a+b);
        }
    });


    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s: arr){
        sb.append(s);
    }

    if(sb.charAt(0) == '0'){     //check if all zeroes are there
        return String.valueOf(0);
    }

    return sb.toString();   
    }
}
```

This works, but I don't know - I don't understand what `Comparator` does, but I know that by interchanging `(b+a)` and `(a+b)` in the code we will get an ascending result - yet I am unable to understand how this is working internally.

Comment: What does "they form the largest number" mean?

Comment: using elements of array we have to create the largest number possible...so this has to be done keeping lexicographic in mind Input: [3,30,34,5,9]
Output: "9534330"

Comment: FWIW, you could use just `Arrays.sort(arr, (a,b) -> (b+a).compareTo(a+b) );` instead of all that yours `Arrays.sort(...)` for readability - `Comparator` is a `@FunctionalInterface` since Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

You could write `a+b` before `b+a`.  But then you would have to switch the arguments to the `compare` method to be b and then a.  But here's the reason for all this.

First, you need to **PRETEND** that `strings` can be compared like `ints` using < and >.

Somewhere in the sort method  you have a construct that compares two values `r` and `s`.

when you sort them, you have a statement like

```
    if (r < s) {
       swap them
    }
```

that sorts them in one direction (perhaps ascending order).

if you do

```
    if (s < r) {
      swap them 
    }
```

that sorts them in the other direction.

When you reverse the order of `r` and `s`, that is what you are doing.  Changing the direction of the sort.

When you concatenate them together you form two different strings `a+b` and `b+a`.  But the process is still the same you compare them in one direction and then the other.  So it's essentially,

```
    r = a+b
    s = b+a
```

and then you compare `r` and `s` as above to get ascending or descending order of the concatenated strings.

Here is a simple sort method and the two `Comparators` to sort `integers` so you can see how they work.  The only difference is which comparison returns -1 vs 1.

```java
      int[] v = { 10, 8, 2, 3, 4, 1, 7, 5, 6, 9
      };

      sort(v, new Comparator<Integer>() {
         public int compare(Integer r, Integer s) {
            if (r < s) {
               return -1;
            }
            if (r > s) {
               return 1;
            }
            return 0;
         }
      });

      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));

      v = new int[] { 10, 8, 2, 3, 4, 1, 7, 5, 6, 9
      };

      sort(v, new Comparator<Integer>() {
         public int compare(Integer r, Integer s) {
            if (s < r) {
               return -1;
            }
            if (s > r) {
               return 1;
            }
            return 0;
         }
      });

      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));
   }

   public static void sort(int[] v, Comparator<Integer> comp) {
      for (int i = 0; i < v.length - 1; i++) {
         for (int k = i + 1; k < v.length; k++) {
            if (comp.compare(v[k], v[i]) < 0) {
               int t = v[i];
               v[i] = v[k];
               v[k] = t;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A and B are strings when they are being compared, so they are not being numerically added, but combined using string concatenation. CompareTo is then looking at the characters in the strings and comparing.

I.e. if a = 1 and b = 2, it's actually a ="1" and b="2"
so a+b="1"+"2" = "12"

Comment: we are dealing here with lets say 9 and 90 , if we have compare it normally the 90 would have come earlier then 9 and we would have 909 as the ans...but 990 is much larger ...that is why concatenation in getting done.....but my ques was in compareto, that why i can't write a+b before b+a

Comment: CompareTo under the hood is evaluating the characters in the strings. That includes looking at the length of the string. It's comparing both strings based on their unicode values.  More info here: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-compareto